# Plot sequence of letters with color in background in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have got the following problem: I have a sequence of letters (a protein sequence) and I would like to give them a colored background based on a value (I have a matching array of numbers). The end result should look something like this:

[image: Example of what I want]

I tried a `pyplot.matshow` by adding my array twice for a 2d array.

```py
figure = plt.figure()
axes = figure.add_subplot(111)

protein_seq='KALEPLMLVMGLISPLAT'
seq_markers= [ protein_seq[i] for i in range(len(protein_seq)) ]

data=np.random.rand(len(protein_seq))
data2d=[data,data]
# randomly generated array
  
# using the matshow() function 
caxes = axes.matshow(data2d, cmap=plt.cm.Reds, vmin=0, vmax=2)

# figure.colorbar(caxes)
  
axes.set_xticklabels(seq_markers)
```

This gives

[image: matshow result]

I am not sure how I get my labels on the matrix. I attempted using markers, but they tend to be small in a figure. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: There are also some examples at https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide the labels to `sns.heatmap`, which also will take care of choosing the text color depending on the cell's darkness.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

figure = plt.figure()
axes = figure.add_subplot(111)

protein_seq = 'KALEPLMLVMGLISPLAT'

data = np.random.rand(len(protein_seq))

sns.heatmap(data=data.reshape(1, -1), annot=np.array([*'KALEPLMLVMGLISPLAT']).reshape(1, -1), fmt='',
            xticklabels=[], yticklabels=[],
            cmap='Reds', vmin=0, vmax=2, square=True, ax=axes, cbar=False)
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.heatmap with custom labels]