# How to customize Seaborn / Matplotlib to display Letters in Matrix with Custom Colors for Backgrounds and Letters

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

We have an open-source Python project that we are developing to share with the world in hopes that the free open-source Python tools that we provide will encourage scientific research and sharing of discoveries in the subject of Equidistant Letter Sequences (ELSs) found cryptographically hidden with the letters of the Hebrew Torah (and perhaps also in other books of the Hebrew Bible).

[TorahBibleCodes.com](https://torahbiblecodes.com)

[GitHub.com/TorahBibleCodes](https://github.com/torahbiblecodes)

In search for how best to allow visualize a 2D matrix of letters, we found this very helpful post:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67751527/plot-sequence-of-letters-with-color-in-background-in-python
```

We were able to hack a bit at the code, but now we need to customize, and would like to request help of those more familiar with Matplotlib and Seaborn.

The following code produces the Matplotlib/Seaborn 2D Matrix image below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

figure = plt.figure()
axes = figure.add_subplot(111)

## L[0:200]
L = ['ב', 'ר', 'א', 'ש', 'י', 'ת', 'ב', 'ר', 'א', 'א', 'ל', 'ה', 'י', 'ם', 'א', 'ת', 'ה', 'ש', 'מ', 'י', 'ם', 'ו', 'א', 'ת', 'ה', 'א', 'ר', 'ץ', 'ו', 'ה', 'א', 'ר', 'ץ', 'ה', 'י', 'ת', 'ה', 'ת', 'ה', 'ו', 'ו', 'ב', 'ה', 'ו', 'ו', 'ח', 'ש', 'ך', 'ע', 'ל', 'פ', 'נ', 'י', 'ת', 'ה', 'ו', 'ם', 'ו', 'ר', 'ו', 'ח', 'א', 'ל', 'ה', 'י', 'ם', 'מ', 'ר', 'ח', 'פ', 'ת', 'ע', 'ל', 'פ', 'נ', 'י', 'ה', 'מ', 'י', 'ם', 'ו', 'י', 'א', 'מ', 'ר', 'א', 'ל', 'ה', 'י', 'ם', 'י', 'ה', 'י', 'א', 'ו', 'ר', 'ו', 'י', 'ה', 'י', 'א', 'ו', 'ר', 'ו', 'י', 'ר', 'א', 'א', 'ל', 'ה', 'י', 'ם', 'א', 'ת', 'ה', 'א', 'ו', 'ר', 'כ', 'י', 'ט', 'ו', 'ב', 'ו', 'י', 'ב', 'ד', 'ל', 'א', 'ל', 'ה', 'י', 'ם', 'ב', 'י', 'ן', 'ה', 'א', 'ו', 'ר', 'ו', 'ב', 'י', 'ן', 'ה', 'ח', 'ש', 'ך', 'ו', 'י', 'ק', 'ר', 'א', 'א', 'ל', 'ה', 'י', 'ם', 'ל', 'א', 'ו', 'ר', 'י', 'ו', 'ם', 'ו', 'ל', 'ח', 'ש', 'ך', 'ק', 'ר', 'א', 'ל', 'י', 'ל', 'ה', 'ו', 'י', 'ה', 'י', 'ע', 'ר', 'ב', 'ו', 'י', 'ה', 'י', 'ב', 'ק', 'ר', 'י', 'ו', 'ם', 'א', 'ח', 'ד', 'ו', 'י', 'א']

SequenceForMatrix = L[0:200]

data = np.random.rand(len(SequenceForMatrix))

sns.heatmap(data=data.reshape(10, -1), annot=np.array([*SequenceForMatrix]).reshape(10, -1), fmt='',
            xticklabels=[], yticklabels=[],
            cmap='Blues', vmin=0, vmax=2, square=True, ax=axes, cbar=False)


plt.show()
```

We would like to customize the following:

1.) Currently the text matrix runs from top left corner (i.e. left-to-right LTF), and since Hebrew is read from right-to-left, we need the matrix to start from the top right corner (i.e. right-to-left RTL)

2.) We need customizable background colors for each square as well as customizable text colors.

Is this possible with Seaborn and Matplotlib?

[TorahBibleCodes 2D Matrix of Hebrew Letters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgBqE.png)

Comment: If you want to control the color of each grid (square), you will need a highly customized colormap. which I don't think is straightforward. I recommend you plot each grid with matplotlib `patches.Rectangle`.

Comment: Indeed, we are looking for the simplest Occam's Razor solution, and are not married to the Seaborn Library. We are seeking to do this project with as few imported libraries as possible. Willing to do this in a Python GUI if necessary. We just need to display a grid, and differentiate different color letters/background for alternating words, and some sort of highlighting individual letters/background for the ELS Search Terms. Any suggestions?  We want to make this as simple as possible for the non-technie to dive right in.